# Compact Framework - Signal Strength

Tags: compact-framework

Is there any class/object in the comapact framework 3.5 that will allow me to check the cellular signal strength of a mobile device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [WindowsMobile.Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemproperty.aspx) class you can check the PhoneSignalStrength property.

Answer (score 1):

I found this using Google http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=29547800&threadid=29547791

Hope it helps